# How can I loop through a csv file and replace values in it with a python dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, csv, file, dictionary-comprehension

This is my dictionary {'0':'Denver', '1':'Chicago', '2':'Maryland'}

in the csv files I have
0  **1**
1  **0**
2  **2**
3  **2**
I would like to change the numbers in the CSV file to the values in the dictionary:
0  **Chicago**
1  **Denver**
2  **Maryland**
3  **Maryland**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
d = {'0':'Denver', '1':'Chicago', '2':'Maryland'}

# we'll start by creating a new file to write the output to
with open("output_filename.csv", "w+") as out_file:
    # So the first piece is reading the file in python
    with open("filename.csv") as in_file:
        # next you'll want to loop over each line
        for line in in_file:
            # Now we can split the string into elements by the whitespce
            line_list = line.split(" ")
            # line_list = ['0', '1', '1', '0', '2', '2', '3', '2']
            # we can loop over the list taking alternating elements and looking them up
            result = " ".join([d[item] if index % 2 else item for index, item in enumerate(line_list)])
            out_file.write(result)
```

The real "work" is happening in this line:
`result = " ".join([d[item] if index % 2 else item for index, item in enumerate(line_list)])`

`enumerate` returns the index and the value as we loop over the line_list so `(0, '0'), (1, '1'), (2, '1') ...`

then the turnery is using the modulo `%` to see what the remainder is when dividing by 2 (ie if the index is 0, 2, 4, ...) and using the dictionary to look up the value if it **isn't** (ie index 1, 3, 5...)

Comment: I suppose the "line_list" is my dictionary. how about the "d"? I'm getting not defined

Comment: Sorry, I added d -- that's the dictionary

the "line_list" is created by splitting the string from your csv `"0 1 1 0 2 2 3 2"` by it's whitespace `line_list = line.split(" ")` resulting in `['0', '1', '1', '0', '2', '2', '3', '2']`

Comment: Maybe I need to clarify a bit. my dictionary has keys and values. Now, these keys are the only values in a CSV file and I want to loop through the CSV file and replace the values with the Key Values from my dictionary where the value = key. IF (ValueInCSV = KeyInDictionary) ValueInCSV = KeyInDictionary->Value

Comment: My code above takes `"0 1 1 0 2 2 3 2"` and ouputs `"0 Chicago 1 Denver 2 Maryland 3 Maryland"`

You just need to replace "filename.csv" with your actual filename,  and "output_filename.csv" with the desired output file